# PostGIS, Indexed Intersecting Generated Geography

Tags: postgresql, indexing, gis, postgis

Ok, I think I've got a weird problem, and I've been having a hell of a time finding answers.

I'll just begin:

I've got a table of devices:

```
  Column  |   Type    |                      Modifiers                       
----------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------
 id       | integer   | not null default nextval('devices_id_seq'::regclass)
 location | geography | 
 radius   | integer   |
```

Which represents the location, and resolution of location, of a bunch of devices.

I want to find which devices are within range of a zone.

So, I can do a query like:

```
SELECT count(id) FROM devices WHERE ST_intersects(ST_buffer(ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(-80.519142 43.460270)'), 20000), ST_buffer(location, radius));
```

Where the hard-coded location will eventually come from a join.

So, I've got devices with uncertainty, and a big zone, and I want to know which devices could be inside that zone.
This query works, but in a test of 100000 devices, it takes 28 seconds.

So I wanted to index it.
It's been all day, and I know things, but not the right answer.

First, doing an index like `CREATE INDEX device_buffer ON devices USING gist (st_buffer(location, radius));` seemed to exist, but looking at the above query it never actually got used.

Looking at the output of explain, it showed `geography(st_transform(st_buffer(st_transform(geometry(location), _st_bestsrid(location, location)), (radius)::double precision), 4326))`, which seems to be the expanded version.

Putting an index on that didn't seem to help either.

So, to figure out if the trouble is `ST_INTERSECT` or me, I did:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW device_buffer_view AS SELECT id, ST_BUFFER(location, radius) as buffer FROM devices;
```

And put an index on the buffer field of that view.
That query hit the index.
Good.
This told me that my buffers can be indexed in an intersection.

This still isn't great, though, since I don't actually want a materialized view.

I want the location and the radius in the table, though, because other parts of the app look at this data, and allow it to be adjusted later. Storing only the resultant Geography is not helpful.

Based on something I found online, I tried:

```
CREATE FUNCTION geog(rec devices) RETURNS geography IMMUTABLE LANGUAGE SQL AS 'SELECT ST_BUFFER($1.location, $1.radius);';
```

Which allows me to do `SELECT devices.geog FROM devices`, and index it, but putting an index like:

```
CREATE INDEX device_geog ON devices USING GIST ((devices.geog));
```

Doesn't work any better when using `devices.geog` in the select query.

So, it seems like I might have to store the geography in the table, which would be fine, and then I can index that.

I wouldn't want it to get denormalized, though.

I tried to make a RULE so that if there was an update to either location or radius, it would automatically recompute the stored geography, but it complained about a recursive rule...

So, is there something really simple I haven't touched on, or some subtle point that I've missed?

I'm pretty confused, and a little frustrated, and maybe even out of my depth.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a weird problem. Using a buffer as a proximity search is a very common mistake to new users. It's much slower, doesn't use a spatial index, and is less precise (since the buffer typically has 16 segments per quarter). Buffering a feature by a radius is visual intuitive, but computationally excessive for a proximity search.

To make the query more reliable and much faster, use [**ST_DWithin**](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html). This function finds the features that are within a specified distance of other features. It will also use a GiST spatial index.

```
SELECT count(id)
FROM devices
WHERE ST_DWithin(location, ST_MakePoint(-80.519142, 43.460270)::geography, radius);
```

And if you need more speed at the cost of less precision, use a spherical distance instead of spheroid, by adding `use_spheroid=false` to the proximity filter.

Comment: I guess, because each of the two points had its own radius, it made more sense to construct circles and ask if they touch, but I guess I could use `ST_DWithin(location, other_location, radius + other_radius)`, to see if the centres are closer than the sum of the radii from each other. Would that reduce the effectiveness of the query?

Comment: Alright, I tried running the query, and I couldn't get it to use an index, but it was way faster than the other query even when the other one did use the index. It didn't return the same result set, it returned 4096 rows rather than 4048, but I don't know which of them is "right". 4096 rows certainly isn't every item in the table.

Comment: Taking out the radius from they query leads to it hitting the index, but apparently I can't put location and radius into the index together, because radius can't go into gist, and it didn't seem to hit the index if I wasn't using gist. Overall, though, the query without the index is very fast, so I don't think I care right now.

Comment: @psycotica0 right, I now recall an index is only used if the distance is fixed. ST_DWithin may return a few more results than a buffer technique, because the buffer does not draw a (e.g.) perfect circle with radius. Imagine a circle and a octagon with identical diameters: the circle will always have the largest area, since there will be gaps near the edges.

Comment: Sure. We're planning on using `DT_DWithin` with `radius + constant_maximum_device_radius` as a first pass, which allows it to hit the index, and then a second pass with the particular radius. Should be good, I think.